# Accessing website from two ports - Apache config

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, virtualhost, port, forwarding

I have a website setup and want to be able to access the same site from two different ports.  Does anybody know how I would do this?
For example, I want to be able to access exactly the same at `http://example.com:5678` as I can at `http://example.com:80`.  I had tried fiddeling with virtualHosts in my httpd.conf from what I read on forums and the docs but couldn't figure it out - any ideas?
Also, how would I be able to make it work for `http://domain1.com:80` shows the same as `http://domain2.com:5678`? (for both where domain1 and domain2 are hosted on same server)

Does WHM/cPanel support this (other than domain parking)?  If not, how would I change my apache to do this?

Thanks

Sam

**Updated**

I am not sure that you understood.  I have a virtualHost set up and want that to be accessible from two different ports, showing exactly the same.  Here is my virtual host currently.

```
<VirtualHost 184.107.24.1:80>
    ServerName example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.co.uk
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.co.uk combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.co.uk-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User example # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled example
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup example example
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup example example
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RUidGid example example
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/public_html/cgi-bin/


    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/example/example.co.uk/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple binding addresses and ports in VirtualHost.

Change

```
<VirtualHost 184.107.24.1:80>
```

To

```
<VirtualHost 184.107.24.1:80 184.107.24.1:5678>
```

You will also need to specify the port outside of the VHost, so your config might look something like this:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 184.107.24.1:80

Listen 5678   
NameVirtualHost 184.107.24.1:5678

<VirtualHost 184.107.24.1:80 184.107.24.1:5678>
    ServerName example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.co.uk
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.co.uk combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.co.uk-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User example # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled example
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup example example
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup example example
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RUidGid example example
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/public_html/cgi-bin/


    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/example/example.co.uk/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

Update for your question:

If you want domain1.com:80 and domain2.com:5678 to display the same content, but do not want domain1.com:80 and domain2.com:800 to be the same...then you will need to seperate the vhosts.

```
<VirtualHost 184.107.24.1:80>
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias *.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 184.107.24.1:5678>
ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias *.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: is what you are saying then that I don't need to use:

          `ProxyRequest Off;
          ProxyPass / http://example.co.uk:5678/;
          ProxyPassReverse / http://example.co.uk:5678/;`

?

Comment: No, you don't need them from what I can tell from your question.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work.  As you can see from the example, it says do not edit because it is automatically generated by WHM/cPanel.  Any idea on how I would add this stuff in more permanently so cPanel doesn't get rid of it?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have much experience with that, sorry. I don't know that you will get much of a response here either. I would suggest posting a new question now that your config is okay, tailored specifically towards cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same domain name just add:

```
Listen 5678
```

In the same location you have

```
Listen 80
```

Comment: thanks, but it says I can't put that into my VirtualHost.  See above update to post.